# Make Gridview horizontally scrolling when pressing arrow keys in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml

My gridview is horizontally scrollable using mouse wheel by default. I need a feature which will enable the same thing using right and left arrow keys.

First of all I tried to handle KeyDown event for Gridview, it didn't work. Then I found this event Window.Current.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated, and it captured all the keys I pressed. So the next step was what to do with scrollviewer. I tried to put my gridview in Scrollviewer in xaml, but it wasnt what I wanted. And the scrollviewer which is by default in gridview, doesn't have any functions which will enable the same thing which is done by mouse wheel. I wanted to perform PointerWheelChanged, but I didnt know what to give as eventargs. Please help me, i'm new to WInRT

P.S. I need this scrolling when the(parent) window has got the focus, but gridviewItem has not. Because if I select an item, i can switch between selected items using arrow keys. (I will not have item selection in my final app).

Comment: Doesn't this work by default?

Comment: No. When gridview loses focus, nothing happens after arrow key pressing.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Well @ChrisW.,  first of all I tried to handle KeyDown event for Gridview, it didn't work. Then I found this event Window.Current.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated, and it captured all the keys I pressed. So the next step was what to do with scrollviewer.

I tried to put my gridview in Scrollviewer in xaml, but it wasnt what I wanted. And the scrollviewer which is by default in gridview, doesn't have any functions which will enable the same thing which is done by mouse wheel. I wanted to perform PointerWheelChanged, but I didnt know what to give as eventargs.

Please help me, i'm new to WInRT

Comment: Steal this code: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/master/Template10%20(Library)/Services/KeyboardService